# how to fill text box which dont have id

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to automate a webpage in VB.net  but I am unable fill values in  text box my code only clicking on button

Webpage HTML as follows

```html
<TD align=left height="25" width="350">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="UserName" size="20">
</TD>
<TD align=left height="25" width="350">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="password" name="Password1" size="20" maxlength="12">
</TD> 
<TD align=left height="25" width="350">&nbsp;
    <input type="button" onClick="UserVer();" value="Submit"name="BLogin">
</TD>
```

My VB.net code is follows:

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = wc.Document
Dim link As HtmlElement
Dim links As HtmlElementCollection = wc.Document.All
Dim dom = doc.GetElementsByTagName("a")
Dim t As HtmlElement = wc.Document.All(Name)

For Each link In links
    If link.GetAttribute("name") = "UserName" Then
        link.SetAttribute("value", UNameTxt.Text)
    End If
Next
For Each link In links
    If link.GetAttribute("name") = "Password1" Then
        link.SetAttribute("value", UPassTxt.Text)
    End If
Next
For Each link In links
    If link.GetAttribute("value") = "Submit" Then

        link.InvokeMember("click")

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why can't they have id's?

Comment: its not my web page it is a external web site

Comment: I dont even... why cant you just send a request to the page where the form submits to?

Comment: i can not use web request because I need to use webbrowser only ,its project requirement

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no control over the source you are trying to automate, then I suggest a library such as [WatiN](http://watin.org/) to assist in selecting the items you wish to work, like this:

Here is an example of going to Google and doing a search using `WatiN`:

```
' Go to URL for Google search
Dim browser As New IE("http://www.google.com/")

' Find the search text box by name and type text `WatiN` in the box
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN")

' Find the search button by name and click the button
browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click()
```

You can find elements by name, style, ID, etc. and then perform actions on the elements.